# Can't start new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Good day, I try to start new Activity from another. But it always crashed.
Here My code. It is the event on ListView.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Student selected = (Student)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String selectedTitle = selected.FirstName;  //ideally this would probably be done with accessors
                int selectedId = selected.studentId;
                String selectedDescription = selected.LastName;

               Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), StudentInfoActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("studentId", selectedId);
               try{
                   startActivity(i);
               }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

A added an activity to Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".StudentInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

An error message is

```
06-15 17:17:00.471: E/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marat.mutw/com.marat.mutw.StudentInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

All previus activities, those I added works fine...

StudentInfoActivity

```
public class StudentInfoActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    TextView firstLastName;
    TextView studentInfo;
    TextView addInfo;
    Student std;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sudentinfolayout);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        firstLastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstNameLastName);
        studentInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.studentinfo);
        addInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);

        int studentId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("studentId");
        JSONHandler handler = new JSONHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
        std = new Student();
        std = handler.GetStudentInfo(studentId);
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(std.imagePath));
        firstLastName.setText(std.FirstName+ "  "+std.LastName);




    }
    public void onClickApply(View view){

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your oncreate for StudentInfoActivity?

Comment: the problem is in StudentInfoActivity.java please provide that

Comment: What's `uriSting` here? And, post your `StudentInfoActivity.java`

Comment: Most likely this exception happened in `onCreate` of the activity you're trying to start.

Comment: looks the problem may be with this line  image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(std.imagePath)); just comment it and try to confirm.......

Comment: you have try this String  studentId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("studentId");int studentIdi=Integer.parseInt(studentId );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), StudentInfoActivity.class);
```

change to

```
Create static object of that activity
```

e.g   Activity actOne =null;

```
public static actOne a ;
a = this;

Intent i = new Intent(a, StudentInfoActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentInfoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("studentId", selectedId);
startActivity(i);
```